# Not able to input string in python for sentiment analysis

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, sentiment-analysis

I have given a path name for sentiment analysis (Google Cloud API, Python). However, when the file is trying to read, it is giving the following error:

```
\r\n\r\n' has type str, but isn't valid UTF-8 encoding. Non-UTF-8 strings must be converted to unicode objects before being added.
```

Please help!. Need to get this working within 16 hours.

Comment: please add your code and the full error message.

Comment: You're probably passing non-ASCII characters to whatever method you're calling. 
Try to delcare your string as `u'Hello, world!'.encode('utf-8')`. Also, post the full code if you want help.